# Secure iNet Factory and Apache httpclient, which one is more powerful?

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I'm new to both of the two libraries. Now I need a java http library in my application. My question is which of the two is more powerful? Thanks.

PS:
Secure iNet Factory:
http://www.jscape.com/secureinetfactory/index.html

Comment: Unless you specify what it is you want to do, it is impossible to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not heard of Secure iNet Factory. However Apache HttpClient is well-documented (including on SO) and I've not found it missing in features or being unreliable. It would be my first call unless I had *very* specific requirements that it failed to meet (and that I can't think of).